# What will be the regex for extracting the data from following string

Tags: java, regex, match, extract

I have to write an application which has to extract the first 16 digits (`0989563275315984`) , `crtext`, `tiff` and `1.0_xcvb-uploadtheDoc-hkl56895-20990415-05:11:24,897-2013027676`

```
0989563275315984-1.0_xcvb-uploadtheDoc-hkl56895-20990415-05:11:24,897-2013027676-crtext-tiff.wrk
```

The regex I've come up with so far is this:

```
([0-9a-zA-Z]+)-(\\d\\.\\d[_0-9a-zA-Z]*)-([0-9a-zA-Z]+).([a-zA-Z]+).([0-9]?).*
```

Is there any way to write an regex for this requirement. Thanks in advance.

Comment: rookie mistake - show us what you have done so far.. Also check out [regexr] (http://www.regexr.com)

Comment: The answer to your question is **yes, there is a way**. Does this answer your actual question (which is "Could someone write me this RegEx please?")? **No**. Constructing a regex like that is simple and does not require much effort, even if you are a "newbie" when it comes to RegEx.

Comment: @Seth i used this `([0-9a-zA-Z]+)-(\\d\\.\\d[_0-9a-zA-Z]*)-([0-9a-zA-Z]+).([a-zA-Z]+).([0-9]?).*` but it is not giving me the correct text in the group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
(\d{16})-(.*?)-(\w+)-(\w+)\.
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lU3wF3/1)

**Explanation:**
`( … )`: Capturing group [sample](https://regex101.com/r/qL1pP8/1)
`\`: Escapes a special character [sample](https://regex101.com/r/aM5iM5/1)
`.`: Any character except line break [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wY6xS4/1)
`*`: Zero or more times [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wE3zV2/1)
`?`: Once or none [sample](https://regex101.com/r/qX9nZ9/1)
`\w`: "word character": ASCII letter, digit or underscore [sample](https://regex101.com/r/uQ2lG4/1)
`+`: One or more [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wV7cV2/1)

Comment: Thanks @Tim007 just changed the first \d to \w as in some scenario i was getting alphanumeric input

Answer (score 1):

Easy!

```
^(\d{16})-(.+)-(\w+)-(\w+)\.wrk$
```

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/aK5fY9/3

### Explanation:

The *secret* is `^` and `$`. `^` is a beginning of string anchor and `$` is and end of string anchor. `{16}` for number of times the character gets shown.